# Python Code gets stuck, not even the CTRL+C helps to exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, debugging, error-handling

I have written code to receive Live market data using Websockets, I analyze the data from within the main Loop (with a sleep time of 0.1 seconds between iterations) and take trading decisions based on the current market levels, from within the main loop I also print the stats every 10 seconds or so. Entire code gets executed within 0.001 seconds (except in some rare cases), so each loop takes about 0.101 seconds (thought these numbers might be helpful). The code runs for 375 minutes a day, I mostly use Visual Code Studio to Write/ Edit and Run code, on Windows 10 64 bit.

The problem I'm facing is that the execution freezes sometimes, The code doesn't print updates, It doesn't execute anything at all, goes comatose.  I can't get out of it even by pressing CTRL+C. If the problem was because of the command getting lost in some corner of the code in an eternal loop, we should have been able to exit it by pressing CTRL+C right? At first I thought this is Visual Studio Code problem, the same happens when I try to Run the code through IDLE

Seems like some basic Python issue, which the knowledgeable coders might be able to pinpoint, Please help me find the bug. Thanks in advance

I tried steps to speed up Visual studio Code, uninstalled extensions that I don't need. But it doesn't look like VSC problem. I'm out of ideas

EDIT:

I have come to the understanding that the problem is most likely happening because of an http request to the broker that doesn't return an acknowledgement (The broker confirmed that the order would be in eternal wait without either a rejection or completion)

So here is what the sample code looks like:

```py
import time
import api

is_in_position=0

def isExit():
    # If exit is necessary return 1 else return 0

def createPosition():
    try:
       result=api.placeOrder('qty'=100, 'action'='buy')
       if result['status']=='OK':
               is_in_position=1
    except:
        print("An Exception has happened (1)")
    
def checkPositionsForChanges():
    # Check Positions, exit if the move is against you
    is_exit=isExit()
    if is_exit:
        try:
            result=api.placeOrder('qty'=100, 'action'='sell')
           if result['status']=='OK':
               is_in_position=2
        except:
            print("An Exception has happened (2)")


# THE MAIN WHILE LOOP
while True:
    if  is_in_position==0:
        createPosition()
        is_in_position=1
     elif is_in_position==1:
        checkPositionsForChange()
     elif is_in_position==2:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem is coming from

```
result=api.placeOrder('qty'=100, 'action'='buy')
```

api.placeOrder is a broker SDK function, it doesn't throw any exception, not even timeout error, and I have no control over that.

How do I work around it, such that the non-response from the broker doesn't stall me

Comment: Too many things that can be happening there. One thing I would make sure is that SIGINT is not overridden somewhere in your code. If it is, that might be the cause for not raising `KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: why run the code from an IDE or IDLE, just run it from the command line, are you running it in a debugger for production execution

Comment: @rioV8 could you please explain this a bit? can interpreters be at fault here? I'll surely try. Thanks

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla I'm very new to Python, I don't know how to do that, but quite possible that  I might have done something unknowingly  :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: why do you need VSC to run your python code? That means for every python program you have running you need to open  a new VSC instance???? Running in a debugger slows down your program.

Comment: @BentheCoder I'd have to post the entire code  of1000 lines, I'm unsure which sections could be considered problem causing. I tried to find sections that can represent the whole and still be enough for debugging, but I couldn't

Comment: @rioV8 "Running in a debugger slows down your program" I guess it habit, I learned my coding on VSC, I'd edit and ;live test, I had been doing it from the start, I guess now is the time to change to good habits, thanks, will do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JialeDu The code is hanging, It stops execution once in a while (happens rarely), I'm suspecting the that the API query I'm making is blocking the process, and the code doesn't use threads.

Comment: Better show your sample code. We cannot reproduce your problem based on these descriptions alone.

Comment: @JialeDu I have added the relevant parts from the main code here (loosely written, for logic only) please help me find the solution for the problem. I'm new to Python, appreciate further help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry my machine can't reproduce your issue, if you have a full bug report and steps to reproduce, you can report it on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) for a response.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, your problem seems to be that the code is entering a loop from which it can't exit. The Ctrl+C command is executed immediately after the current command finishes, but if this command is an extremely large calculation (or an API call that might time out), it wouldn't work and you would need to force the stop of the execution of VSCode.

Without taking a look at the code, is a bit difficult to find the exact problem, but I might try to add a timeout when receiving your stock data.

Hope that this help!

Comment: "As you mention, your problem seems to be that the code is entering a loop from which it can't exit." I'm of the opinion that it is not the problem. 

Yeah, it makes sense. I use websockets (about 500 updates a second, auto update the data into a list) and then run analysis on the updates every 0.1 second, some mess up there  is certainly possible. Thanks for your inputs